# Удаленный запуск powershell с Linux машины через ssh

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, active-directory

Всем привет.

С толкнулся с проблемой запуска powershell скриптов на сервере Windows через ssh клиента на Linux.

Ситуация следующая:

На windows сервере лежит powershell скрипт. Допустим с одной командой:

```
echo "Hello"
```

Далее я хочу его исполнить через ssh на Linux:

```
ssh user@server "powershell script_name.ps1"
```

После этой команды получаю вывод на консоли Hello, т.е все работает, все хорошо.

Но проблема возникает с запуском некоторых командлетов, а именно, если в скриптах powershell используются команды Get-AdUser и подобные, то они не работают:

```
ssh user@server "powershell Get-AdUser testuser"
```

> get-aduser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is c
>   urrently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + get-aduser testuser
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (testuser:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADServerDownEx
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comman
>      ds.GetADUser

Если зайти на сервер Windows локально, и запустить эту команду, то все работает корректно.

Видимо где-то не хватает прав, не получилось разобраться.

На Windows сервере стоит OpenSSH сервер, авторизация по ключу. Дополнительно пробовал импортировать вручную модуль Active-Directory - не помогает.

Куда копать?

Comment: Ну на сколько я знаю - штуки для работы с AD в линукс Майки пока не перетащили. Я ради заведения учёток запускаю целую виртуалку с win7.

Comment: А при чем тут работа с AD через Linux? Если в качестве целевой системы выступает Windows? Просто необходимо запустить командлет на Windows через ssh на Linux. Я не использую pwsh и тд, прочитайте еще раз все что я описал. Спасибо

Comment: Перечитал вопрос ещё раз. Я правильно понимаю, `user@server` в `ssh user@server "powershell Get-AdUser testuser"` - это виндовый пользователь на компе с виндой?

Comment: Поймите, что когда вы запускаете сервис, он пытается сбросить всё, что можно, и оставить минимальный минимум (простите за тавтологию). В Unix я бы первым делом смотрел переменные окружения и права пользователя, от которого *реально* запускается форкнутый клиент, из которого в свою очередь запускается нечто, в вашем случае Power Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается тремя командами.

Сперва заполняем данные аутентификации:

```
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList "$($srv[0].user)@$($srv[0].domain)", (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $srv[0].pass -AsPlainText -Force )
```

Далее создаем новую сессию с контроллером(не есть хорошо т.к получается Linux->Windows->DC но могло бы быть просто Linux->Windows)

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $srv[0].dc -Credential $creds -Authentication Negotiate
```

И вызываем команду:

```
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-ADUser testuser }
```

Костыль №2

Можно завести дополнительную задачу на сервере с запуском по времени. Также работает, но связь уже будет не Linux->Windows, а Windows->Linux.